# 'XXX' provides no match for the signature 'new (): XXX'

Tags: typescript

I have the following class, and I am getting this error in the for loop:

> [ts]
>   Argument of type 'Component' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType'.
>     Type 'Component' provides no match for the signature 'new (): Component'

This class looks like this:

```
class Prefab {

    public components: Component[] = [];

    public static make(object: Prefab): GameObject {
        let go = new GameObject;
        for (let comp of object.components) {
            // The error is here:
            go.addComponent(comp);
        }
        return go;
    }

}
```

I then have this interface for my component class:

```
interface ComponentType<T extends Component> {
    new (): T;
}
```

Here is the definition for `addComponent`:

```
addComponent<T extends Component>(type: ComponentType<T>): T;
```

What can I do here?

Answer (score -1):

In the `for` loop, the comp variable refers to `Component` type.

```
for (let comp of object.components) {
```

whereas your `addComponent` method takes `ComponentType<T>` type

```
addComponent<T extends Component>(type: ComponentType<T>): T;
```

`Component` and `ComponentType<T>` don't have the same type which is causing the error.

Comment: How come I can do this: `addComponent(MyComponent)` where that looks like this `class MyComponent extends Component {}`?

Comment: I figured it out. Just needed to change `public components: Component[] = [];` to this `public components: ComponentType<Component>[] = [];`

Comment: Yeah that makes both the types same.